# SharpSVN SvnUI.Bind to WPF window

Tags: wpf, bind, sharpsvn

I am guessing there is no way to Bind call SharpSVN in a WPF application?  I was just following there tutorial, and I found out that you can't bind becuase this isn't a Windows.Forms application.  Quite the bummer.  I was really cooking there for a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the answer is: No.

For compatibility SharpSvn is compiled against .Net 2.0, so doesn't have access to the WPF classes.

You could implement your own IWin32Window to provide a Hwnd.

Googling a bit provided me this sample code.

```
public class Window1 : Window, IWin32Window
{
   public IntPtr Handle
   {
      get
      {
         var interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
         return interopHelper.Handle;
      }
   }
}
```