# Save locally SVN authentication credentials with SharpSVN

Tags: c#, svn, authentication, sharpsvn

I’m using SharpSVN.

I want to store the SVN credential in pc.

I have try to set credentials updating default credentials

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
    ...
}
```

but it doesn't save the data.

I have found that SharpSvn give a default GUI to input credentials. This GUI has a flag to store the data. Here the links where I found information:

- http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/sharpsvn-brings
- [SharpSVN SvnUI.Bind to WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760846/sharpsvn-svnui-bind-to-wpf-window)
- http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/docs/walkthrough.htm#svn_commit

Here the code to use it:

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    // Bind the SharpSvn UI to our client for SSL certificate and credentials
    SharpSvn.UI.SharpSvnUI.Bind(client, IWin32Window);
    ....
}
```

But it is make for  Windows.Forms and I use WPF.
Also, I couldn't use this default GUI.

Someone now how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer!

For **save credentials** in the computer in use

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    //Save localy new Authentication credentials
    client.Authentication.UserNamePasswordHandlers
    += delegate(object obj, SharpSvn.Security.SvnUserNamePasswordEventArgs args)
    {
        args.UserName = "username";
        args.Password = "password";
        args.Save= true;
    };
}
```

Frequently I found the solution to add credentials in **cache**, but this will not store credentials in computer. This credentials are valid only for SvnClient life.
I report the answer for completeness

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    // Clear a previous authentication
    client.Authentication.Clear(); 
    client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
}
```

I found part of the answer here

- [Setting commit author in SharpSvn .NET library throws SvnRepisitoryIOException exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668389/setting-commit-author-in-sharpsvn-net-library-throws-svnrepisitoryioexception-e)
- [SVN Repository Authentication using SharpSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099392/svn-repository-authentication-using-sharpsvn)

And here:

http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=140680&dsForumId=728

looking at method  DialogUserNamePasswordHandler

http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/svn/sharpsvn/trunk/src/SharpSvn.UI/SvnClientUIHandler.cs

For access use:

- username: guest
- password not needed

Comment: The .Authentication.Clear() unhooks the on disk credential cache. If you remobe the .Clear() the .Save=true will save the credentials as expected.